# Self executing delete files

Tags: windows, batch-file

How would I create a self executing batch file to delete files in a specific folder.
  Scenario:  I have a folder on a server where all the scannered documents go to once they have been scanned. They want a the scanned documents to be deleted after 1 day. Can a batch file be created to do that everyday?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) - this can call a batch file, or just about anything.

(I am assuming Windows, since you mention batch files).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a well known method, and was documented in MSDN some time ago. This technique works on both Windows 95 and Windows NT. It works because MS-DOS batch files are able to delete themselves. To test this technique, create a small batch file containing the single command:

```
del %0.bat
```

The batch file, when run, deletes itself and issues an error "The batch file cannot be found". This error is just a simple message, so it can be safely ignored. By itself this isn't too useful, but when modified to delete our executable it solves our problem, albeit in a rather forceful manner. Our executable will create a batch file (called C:\DelUs.bat) with the following content:

```
:Repeat 
del "C:\MYDIR\MYPROG.EXE" 
if exist "MYPROG.EXE" goto Repeat 
rmdir "C:\MYDIR" 
del "\DelUS.bat"
```

This batch file repeatedly attempts to delete the specified file, and will run continuously consuming CPU until it succeeds. When the execuable has been deleted, the batch file then deletes itself.

The executable needs to spawn off the batch file using CreateProcess, and then should exit immediately. It would be a good idea to give the batch file's thread of execution a low priority so that it doesn't get much execution time until the original executable has terminated.

Read the entire article at http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables that contains the full code to this technique.